# How to remove user_permissions from django admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, user-permissions

let me know how to remove the user_permission field from user and groups in a model as shown in below pic

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove a field from the default user admin by overriding the UserAdmin Class [[source]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/712fe12466cfe4b7e31c61418c85ce36a211261a/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L41)

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # ...
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
        'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions'),
    }),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
)

admin.site.register(UserModel, CustomUserAdmin)
```

[See detailed example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-admin-full-example)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove user_permission

```
exclude = ('user_permissions',)
```

Comment: Please include more detail on where this change is made? A more complete code example will help people.

Answer (score 0):

Completing @SATYA's answer, you can do the following:

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('user_permissions',)

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

You could also extend Django's UserAdmin (from django.contrib.auth.admin), but this could mess up if you use a custom User model.